Error in sending transaction using Jito-ts bundler
This is the initial stage in sending lamports, will try to send a bundle later on
// USE npx ts-node script.ts to run this .ts
require("dotenv").config();

// import { searcherClient } from "jito-ts/dist/sdk/block-engine/searcher";
const { searcherClient } = require("jito-ts/dist/sdk/block-engine/searcher");

import * as Web3 from "@solana/web3.js";
import { Connection, Keypair } from "@solana/web3.js";
import * as Fs from "fs";
import { onBundleResult, sendBundles } from "./utils/utilities";

import bs58 from "bs58";
export type JitoRegion = "mainnet" | "amsterdam" | "frankfurt" | "ny" | "tokyo";
export const JitoEndpoints = {
    mainnet: "https://mainnet.block-engine.jito.wtf/api/v1/transactions",
    amsterdam:
        "https://amsterdam.mainnet.block-engine.jito.wtf/api/v1/transactions",
    frankfurt:
        "https://frankfurt.mainnet.block-engine.jito.wtf/api/v1/transactions",
    ny: "https://ny.mainnet.block-engine.jito.wtf/api/v1/transactions",
    tokyo: "https://tokyo.mainnet.block-engine.jito.wtf/api/v1/transactions",
};

export function getJitoEndpoint(region: JitoRegion) {
    return JitoEndpoints[region];
}

export async function sendTxUsingJito({
    serializedTx,
    region = "ny",
}: {
    serializedTx: Uint8Array | Buffer | number[];
    region: JitoRegion;
}) {
    let rpcEndpoint = getJitoEndpoint(region);
    let encodedTx = bs58.encode(serializedTx);
    let payload = {
        jsonrpc: "2.0",
        id: 1,
        method: "sendTransaction",
        params: [encodedTx],
    };
    let res = await fetch(`${rpcEndpoint}?bundleOnly=true`, {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(payload),
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    });
    let json = await res.json();
    if (json.error) {
        throw new Error(json.error.message);
    }
    return json;
}

async function main() {
    const connection = new Connection(
        Web3.clusterApiUrl("mainnet-beta"),
        "confirmed"
    );
    const decodedKey = new Uint8Array(
        JSON.parse(
            Fs.readFileSync("/home/muhammad/wallet/keypair1.json").toString()
        ) as number[]
    );
    const keypair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(decodedKey);
    console.log(keypair.publicKey.toBase58());
    const to = Keypair.generate();
    const transferTx = new Web3.Transaction();
    const { lastValidBlockHeight, blockhash } =
        await connection.getLatestBlockhash();

    transferTx.add(
        Web3.SystemProgram.transfer({
            fromPubkey: keypair.publicKey,
            toPubkey: to.publicKey,
            lamports: 0.001 * Web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
        })
    );

    transferTx.feePayer = keypair.publicKey;
    transferTx.sign(keypair);
    transferTx.recentBlockhash = blockhash;
    let txSerialize = transferTx.serialize();
    // Send Transaction using Jito
    try {
        const response = await sendTxUsingJito({
            serializedTx: txSerialize,
            region: "ny", // Specify the desired region
        });

        console.log("Transaction sent successfully:", response);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error sending transaction:", error);
    }
}

main();

By running this script npx ts-node script.ts results in the error below.
Error: Package subpath './dist/lib/client' is not defined by "exports" in /home/muhammad/Desktop/PhantomXBackPackConnect/node_modules/rpc-websockets/package.json


from your code it seems that you aren't using the typescript client, so I think you can get rid of it and use the RPC methods instead.

I just faced the same issue but related to @pythnetwork/pyth-solana-receiver
Error: Package subpath './dist/lib/client' is not defined by "exports" in /Users/chester/node_modules/rpc-websockets/package.json
the way i solve it is to change the version of
"@pythnetwork/price-service-client": "^1.9.0",
"@pythnetwork/pyth-solana-receiver": "0.7.0",
in package.json.
Therefore, for me, the issue occurs by version dismatched, and when i switched to the right version, the issue just solved, hope this can give you some insights

So In my case which thing is causing me an the issue?

from my case, it not your code, its the version of packages, check your package.json file and check the versions i have mentioned about
